# Reading TIGER/Line gdb file into R

Tags: r, geospatial

I am using the following [instructions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151613/how-to-read-feature-class-in-file-geodatabase-using-r) to read a TIGER/Line gdb into R.

The first commands work correctly and print out the feature classes:

```
fgdb <- "ACS_2014_5YR_BG_48_TEXAS.gdb"

subset(ogrDrivers(), grepl("GDB", name))
fc_list = ogrListLayers(fgdb)
print(fc_list)

 [1] "ACS_2014_5YR_BG_48_TEXAS"            "BG_METADATA_2014"                   
 [3] "X00_COUNTS"                          "X01_AGE_AND_SEX"                    
 [5] "X02_RACE"                            "X03_HISPANIC_OR_LATINO_ORIGIN"      
 [7] "X07_MIGRATION"                       "X08_COMMUTING"                      
 [9] "X09_CHILDREN_HOUSEHOLD_RELATIONSHIP" "X11_HOUSEHOLD_FAMILY_SUBFAMILIES"   
[11] "X12_MARITAL_STATUS_AND_HISTORY"      "X14_SCHOOL_ENROLLMENT"              
[13] "X15_EDUCATIONAL_ATTAINMENT"          "X16_LANGUAGE_SPOKEN_AT_HOME"        
[15] "X17_POVERTY"                         "X19_INCOME"                         
[17] "X20_EARNINGS"                        "X21_VETERAN_STATUS"                 
[19] "X22_FOOD_STAMPS"                     "X23_EMPLOYMENT_STATUS"              
[21] "X24_INDUSTRY_OCCUPATION"             "X25_HOUSING_CHARACTERISTICS"        
[23] "X27_HEALTH_INSURANCE"                "X99_IMPUTATION"                     
attr(,"driver")
[1] "OpenFileGDB"
attr(,"nlayers")
[1] 24
```

However, when I try to import specific feature classes, the following error occurs:

```
> X01 = readOGR(dsn=fgdb,layer="X01_AGE_AND_SEX")
Error in readOGR(dsn = fgdb, layer = "X01_AGE_AND_SEX") : 
  no features found
In addition: Warning message:
In ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  :
  ogrInfo: all features NULL
```

These feature classes  *do not*  contain geometry data, which may be why there are no features found.

Is there workaround to read non-geometry feature classes into R from a gdb file ?  The only solution I've found so far is to use GDAL command line tools to export the feature class to csv which would then be read into R, but I would like to cut out this middle step.

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV output.csv ACS_2014_5YR_BG_48_TEXAS.gdb X01_AGE_AND_SEX
```